# No source attachment found in com.esri.arcgisruntime maven dependency

Tags: java, esri

I tried all the versions then also not able to get the source file for this.

[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project projectname: Compilation failure
error: cannot access ServiceFeatureTable

[image]

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myfarmony</groupId>
<artifactId>farmsystem</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <zk.version>8.5.0</zk.version>
    <commons-io>1.3.1</commons-io>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <packname>-${project.version}-FL-${maven.build.timestamp}</packname>
    <spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>The farmpro Project</name>
<description>The farmpro Project</description>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>ZK EVAL</id>
        <name>ZK Evaluation Repository</name>
        <url>http://mavensync.zkoss.org/eval</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>esri</id>
        <name>Geotools repository arcgis-java </name>
        <url>https://dl.bintray.com/esri/arcgis/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Geotools repository</name>
        <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>GNU LESSER GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE, Version 3</name>
        <url>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
</licenses>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myfarmony</groupId>
        <artifactId>comfarmpro</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myfarmony</groupId>
        <artifactId>farmtheme</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myfarmony</groupId>
        <artifactId>farmadmintheme</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>calendar</groupId>
        <artifactId>colorbox</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ZK Calendar -->

    <!-- My Sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jpeg Reader dependency for CMYK image -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sanselan</groupId>
        <artifactId>sanselan</artifactId>
        <version>0.97-incubator</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.esri.arcgisruntime/arcgis-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.esri.arcgisruntime</groupId>
        <artifactId>arcgis-java</artifactId>
        <version>100.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-shapefile -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-data -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-data</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.gdal</groupId>
       <artifactId>gdal</artifactId>
       <version>1.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-geojson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-geojson</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.esri.geometry/esri-geometry-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.esri.geometry</groupId>
        <artifactId>esri-geometry-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zkoss.chart</groupId>
        <artifactId>zkcharts</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3-Eval</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>purge-local-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>purge-local-repository</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <manualIncludes>
                            <manualInclude>org.zkoss.zk:zkex</manualInclude>
                            <manualInclude>org.zkoss.zk:zkmax</manualInclude>
                        </manualIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Run with Tomcat -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
                <port>8080</port>
                <contextFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/context.xml</contextFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Compile java -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Build war -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Pack zips -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>webapp</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>farmpro${packname}</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/webapp.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Feature Controller:

```
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.data.ServiceFeatureTable;   
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.layers.FeatureLayer;

public class FeatureController {
     public static void main(String []args) {
        ServiceFeatureTable featureTable = new ServiceFeatureTable("url");
        FeatureLayer featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(featureTable);
     }
}
```

Comment: can you post your complete POM. need to have a look at plugins

Comment: The [repo you point to](https://dl.bintray.com/esri/arcgis/com/esri/arcgisruntime/arcgis-java/100.7.0/) doesn't have any `-sources.jar` for `arcgis-java`.

Comment: I am getting arcgis-java-100.7.0-sources.jar.lastUpdated after I update maven